# How to build CLM for android using Androidndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, android.mk

I was trying to build CLM for android. I create Android.mk file, while building its throws exception 
My android.mk file look like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

include /Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := CLM

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := CCNF_patch_expert.cpp CLM_utils.cpp CLM.cpp CLMTracker.cpp DetectionValidator.cpp Patch_experts.cpp PAW.cpp PDM.cpp SVR_patch_expert.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /Documents/Mk/C-Projects/CLM/include\
                    /Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include\
                    /Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv\
                    /Documents/Mk/C-Projects/CLM/eigen3



LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Building this mk file file i got exceptions

> In file included from
>   /Documents/Mk/C-Projects/CLM/include/CLM_utils.h:9:0,
>                    from jni/CCNF_patch_expert.cpp:3: /Documents/Mk/C-Projects/CLM/include/CLM.h:170:15: error: expected ','
>   or '...' before '&&' token   CLM(const CLM&& other)
>                  ^ /Documents/Mk/C-Projects/CLM/include/CLM.h:170:23: error: invalid constructor; you probably meant 'CLMTracker::CLM (const
>   CLMTracker::CLM&)'   CLM(const CLM&& other)
>                          ^ /Users/hubmaci7/Documents/Mourish/SWIG/C-Projects/CLM/include/CLM.h:192:28:
>   error: expected ',' or '...' before '&&' token   CLM & operator=
>   (const CLM&& other)
>                               ^ /Documents/Mk/C-Projects/CLM/include/CLM.h: In copy constructor
>   'CLMTracker::CLM::CLM(const CLMTracker::CLM&)':
>   /Users/hubmaci7/Documents/Mourish/SWIG/C-Projects/CLM/include/CLM.h:121:32:
>   error: '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list
>   for(std::map>::const_iterator it =
>   other.kde_resp_precalc.begin(); it!= other.kde_resp_precalc.end();
>   it++)
>                                   ^ /Documents/Mourish/SWIG/C-Projects/CLM/include/CLM.h:124:60: error:
>   '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list
>       this->kde_resp_precalc.insert(std::pair>(it->first, it->second.clone()));
>                                                               ^ /Documents/Mk/C-Projects/CLM/include/CLM.h: In member function
>   'CLMTracker::CLM& CLMTracker::CLM::operator=(const CLMTracker::CLM&)':
>   /Documents/Mk/C-Projects/CLM/include/CLM.h:158:33: error: '>>' should
>   be '> >' within a nested template argument list
>       for(std::map>::const_iterator it = other.kde_resp_precalc.begin(); it!= other.kde_resp_precalc.end();
>   it++)

Please help me to find right solution to build clm for android

Answer (score 0):

I got answer to Build CLM in android using Androidndk. In Application.mk file i did mistake i didnt add CPP_FLAGS -std=c++11.

My Application.mk file look like this

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11

APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

Finally i build so generation for CLM

Comment: can you tell me what CLM is, is it a company ?